# Java Locale region and country are missing. What could cause that?

Tags: java, windows, java-8, locale

I am on Windows 10. I have recently installed a JDK 11 alongside a JDK 8, and I supposed this caused the problem.

For Java 1.8.0_181-b13 `Locale.getDefault()` returns Locale with language set to `en` and no country or region is defined, so I can't get a proper currency formatting.

Yet my location is set to Russia in Windows settings.

What could cause the problem?

I know that the default is determined off `user.language`, `user.country` properties and etc. Where are they defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was writing a plugin for a software. Turned out, that the software changes locale at runtime.